# Anchor Tags Not Visible

Tags: html, css

This is very weird. So I'm making a simple navigation menu. I added anchor tags inside my list items but the thing I don't understand is that the more I move them to the right, they're not showing up as links but just list items. I know in this demo it shows them working but in my code they don't show up as links. What is wrong? Do I need to add a pointing cursor? I thought links automatically gave you them.

```css
.nav {
display: flex;
position: relative;
align-items: center;
height: 50px;
margin: 50px 200px 0 200px;
width: calc(100% - 400px); }
.nav a {
display: flex;
align-items: center; }
.nav a img {
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px; }
.nav .desktop {
position: absolute;
right: 0; }
.nav .desktop ul li {
  display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#"><img src="/images/ff_logo_black.png" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="desktop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could it be that an other part of your css/ js changes the style of your html?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my h1 element covering them since it was positioned rather large. Silly me.